# How to add elasticsearch analyzer to searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, search, searchkick

I installed *analysis-ukrainian* to *Searchkick* plugins. Now how should I use it via *Searchkick*?

I tried setting Searchkick language to "ukrainian" but an error accure during reindex:

> Invalid stemmer class specified: Ukrainian.

Please, help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Searchkick doesn't support most analysis plugins with the `language` option. I've added support specifically for Ukrainian to the master branch. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Thank fo adding Ukrainian language support, but after updating `searchkick`,  I've got an error `'searchkick': Invalid value for callbacks (ArgumentError)`. I'm using `searchkick callbacks: [:async, :queue]` and by documentation all ok https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#queuing.

Comment: And all the same i've got an error `Invalid stemmer class specified: Ukrainian` although i've upgraded searchkick

Comment: The `callbacks` option doesn't accept an array, which is why you're seeing the first error (it was silently ignored in Searchkick 2). If you're still seeing the stemming error, you're likely not on the master branch.

Comment: `If you're still seeing the stemming error, you're likely not on the master branch.` how, branch on which I now, is depending to using Ukrainian stemmer? I have not opportunity to work on master branch

Comment: I added support for the Ukrainian stemmer yesterday, so it hasn't been released yet. If you don't want to use the master branch, you'll need to wait until the next release. I don't have a specific date for that yet.